# unique up to unique up to unique up to...

Tags: category-theory, soft-question

For a scheme $S$ and $S$-prestack $\mathscr{X}$, there exists a unique (up to unique (up to unique $2$-isomorphism) $1$-isomorphism.) stackification.

In more higher category theory, is there a similar situation?
i.e., is there an object "unique up to unique up to unique up to... up to unique $n$-isomorpshim $(n-1)$-isomorphism... $1$-isomorphism"?

And if so, I want to know references which includes the sentence as above.

Comment: Wow, that's confusing!  If that's a thing (and I have no reason to doubt it is) time to introduce some more helpful terminology to encapsulate it!

Comment: Yes, indeed you can go all the way up to (weak/strict) $\omega$-categories.

Comment: The formulation among homotopy-theory-minded people is "up to a contractible space of choices".